# If $A \in \Sigma_1 \setminus \Sigma_2$ and $B \in \Sigma_2 \setminus \Sigma_1$, prove that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ be sigma algebras on the same set X such that $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ is also a sigma-algebra. Prove that for $A, B \subseteq X$, such that $A \in \Sigma_1 \setminus \Sigma_2$ and $B \in \Sigma_2 \setminus \Sigma_1$, it always holds that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

We have $A,B\in\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$ and consequently $A\cup B\in\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$.

WLOG we assume that $A\cup B\in\Sigma_1$.

Then $B=(A\cup B)\cap A^c\in\Sigma_1$ and a contradiction is found.